# SQL how to append columns to a single-row result set?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

The issue arises from the need to return values from need to return a single-row result set that will be used for a web service.

For example, if I have a select statement which currently returns a result set with 3 columns and 1 row, is there a way to "append" a value to it in its own column? The new value could be the result of any arbitrary select which returns exactly one row.

`select a, b, c from d where a = 'id'` gives

```
col1   col2   col3
  a      b      c
```

The new select should give:

```
col1   col2   col3   col4
  a      b      c    *NEW*
```

Arbitrary in this case is used to mean not necessarily related to any of the values or tables in the original select statement.

I want to know how to do this in Oracle, but hopefully there is a solution which uses standard SQL features so most databases will handle it.

**EDIT**: By `NEW` I don't mean the string literal 'NEW', but I mean the result of the new select statement that I want to "append".

Comment: This sounds really odd and would cause me to question your database schema design if you need to do this.

Comment: This query is meant to be used for a web service, where it needs a single-row of values.

Comment: OK but why do you need to have the values in the same query.  You can query the database for this data and represent it however you want in the response to the client?

Comment: That is the point -- to avoid having anything in the middle layer on for this query.

Comment: OK then you don't have a web service, you just have a client directly calling a database. When you say you this query is to be used for a web service, this would lead me to think you have a web service through which you provide this data to a service client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a new select statement, you can do that in two ways.  One is a `select` within a `select`:

```
select col1, col2, col3, 
       (select 'NEW' from d limit 1) as col4
from d
```

The other is a `cross join`:

```
 select d.col1, d.col2, d.col3, const.col4
 from d cross join
      (select 'NEW' as col4 from d limit 1) const
```

I am using a simple subquery just as an example.  I assume your subquery is a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    a, b, c,
    (select smth from table2 limit 1) as col4 as col4
from d where a = 'id'
```

The second query should return exactly one row and one column

Answer (score 0):

this type of structure will work.  note you will get a cross join when there are more than one row.

```
select a,b,c,d
from ( select a,b,c from dual )
, (select d from dual )
```